# Circular number system that allows division by zero.

Tags: calculus, limits

Division by zero is not allowed, even in the limit. We can't just say $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x} = \infty$. The limit doesn't exist because approaching from the positive side and negative side yield results as different as you can get.

But, there is a circular number system where this does become possible. You then require the number line to be the limit of a really large circle instead of an infinitely extending straight line. Hence, $\infty$ and $-\infty$ become the same and the problem of the limit not existing goes away.

First, what is this circular number system called? I remember reading about it a while back, but can't find it anywhere now.

Second, being able to divide by zero is a nice ability. So, why don't we switch to this circular number system? What are the cons?

Comment: Topologically, this is the one point compactification of the reals.

Comment: What problem do we run into in trying to make it behave like numbers?

Comment: Are you looking for  Riemann sphere  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403128/the-riemann-sphere-interpretation?

Comment: Just one obvious example: the $<$ relation no longer works.

Comment: A less obvious example: there's no $x$ for which $\infty+x=0$, which means that from $a+c=b+c$ you can no longer infer $a=b$. (You might have $1+\infty=2+\infty$.)  And to even write “$-c$” or “$x-c$” you would have to show first that $c≠∞$, just as in regular algebra you may not discuss $c^{-1}$ or $\frac xc$ without first showing $c≠0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a geometric  or topological object, this is called the [*real projective line*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_line).  But it's not a "number system" because there is no way to make it behave like numbers in any useful way. See [Why not to extend the set of natural numbers to make it closed under division by zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125186/why-not-to-extend-the-set-of-natural-numbers-to-make-it-closed-under-division-by/125208) for details of what goes wrong.